# Passing a CLLLocation array from Objective-c produces a crash

Tags: objective-c, arrays, swift, nsarray

Since recently when I try to pass an array of CLLocation from an Objective-c module to a Swift one I get:

> fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element
>   type

This is how I call the functions:

```
routeLine = [PreloadedLine lineWithLoadedPath:preloadedPath 
    key:lineKey 
    andNotification:(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)];
```

and here is the Swift signature for the function:

```
class func lineWithLoadedPath(path: [CLLocation]?, 
    key:String?, 
    andNotification notification:Bool)->Line?
```

And this is the Objective-c signature for it:

```
+ (Line * __nullable)lineWithLoadedPath:(NSArray<CLLocation *> * __nullable)path 
    key:(NSString * __nullable)key 
    andNotification:(BOOL)notification;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also ported the latter class to Swift along with its hierarchy and this problem got away by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Believe the error message. Something that isn't a CLLocation is getting into the NSArray.

So, on the Objective-C side, you are saying:

```
 [PreloadedLine lineWithLoadedPath:preloadedPath ...
```

...but `preloadedPath` is an NSArray with stuff in it that isn't all CLLocations, so on the Swift side, the app blows up.

Comment: As a matter of fact the value I passed was an NSArray of CLLocations. And between them there should be a token free bridging. At any rate I took this matter as an excuse for porting the massive class to swift, and I hope that shall improve the things.  All in all I think the Swift Objective-c interoperability i being strongly degrading recently, perhaps as a way to push developers to adopt Swift, I do not know.

Comment: "All in all I think the Swift Objective-c interoperability i being strongly degrading recently" That's flapdoodle. You're not going to understand what you're doing wrong until and unless you admit to yourself that _you_ are to blame, not some mysterious gremlin inserted into "the Swift Objective-C interoperability".

Comment: It may be so, but once I ported the class to Swift, the problems went away. Apparently NSArrays of CLLocations do not travel well between Objective-c and Swift.